# Temporary Failure in Name Resolution

Tags: linux, networking, kali-linux, windows-subsystem-for-linux, tor

Downloaded Kali Linux as a Windows app (WSL). Installed TorGhost. When I run `sudo torghost --start`, I get this:

```
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='fathomless-tor-66488.herokuapp.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /latestversion (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7fba5bba20d0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution',))
```

It's not just TorGhost that does this. If I try to ping google.com, I get the same thing: "Temporary failure in name resolution". I know it's able to connect to the internet because I can download programs and such.

I'll admit, I'm not a linux networking nerd who knows everything about the operating system like the rest of you all, so I'm not really sure where to start here.

I saw here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53687051/ping-google-com-temporary-failure-in-name-resolution that a possible solution might be to edit the `resolv.conf` file, but it's set to localhost, and I don't really know what could be wrong with that.

Comment: @harrymc The link you gave me sent me to an image of a program running diagnostics on an SSD. Not sure if this is unintentional, or if there's something I'm missing here.

Comment: Sorry, copy-paste failure. I meant [this one](https://superuser.com/a/1571372/8672).

Comment: @harrymc Ah, okay, thank you. I will try this.