# Win10 laptop has one ethernet port. Currently on Win10 is able to connect to the LAN, but not WSL2. How to enable WSL2 to connect?

Tags: networking, wsl2

I need to access the LAN via WSL2 using command line.  When I attempt to ssh or ping a device, the response say network is unreachable.  I have no issue doing the same on windows.

Comment: Try [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1571372/8672).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Network problems using WSL2](https://superuser.com/questions/1570310/network-problems-using-wsl2)