# DNS responses are not used by the system but nslookup works

Tags: windows, windows-10, networking, dns, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am setting up a Windows computer. It is a rather strange setup, but it is necessary my company's workflows developed on Linux will also work here. I will add background information to the end. But first the facts.

- I have an Ubuntu System set up in Windows 10 with WSL2.
- The Ubuntu System is a gateway to a local subnet.
- Inside the local subnet I have a private DNS server running.

  - This DNS Server has `8.8.8.8` as a fallback server, if it doesn't know the answer
  - It is the only DNS Server set in Windows, no other DNS servers are there
- When I open PowerShell and nslookup a domain — either in the `www` or the `local` subnet — I receive the correct response. (Windows)
- When I ping the domain or open it in a web browser it cannot look it up. This if for both public and private domains (Windows)
- When I ping the IP address returned from nslookup or open it works perfectly fine (Windows)
- When I ping dnsdock and it works (Ubuntu WSL2)

All the responses are non-authorative, which makes perfect sense, since it's forwarded through a private DNS server. Is Windows ignoring non-authorative answers?

**Background**

I think that describes my problem, but I think it's inevitable that I will get comments asking why my setup is that complicated. It's a computer for one of our developers. We are developing within Docker and inside Ubuntu Docker is installed natively (not via Docker desktop) because that allowed for forwarding to the actual containers.

I can ping them. To do so, I had to set up Ubuntu as a router (IPv4 forwarding to active and IP Table rules for forwarding). I also had to write a PowerShell script that reset the route on login because the IP address of Ubuntu changes on every startup. The private DNS server is [DNSDock](https://github.com/aacebedo/dnsdock). It connects to the Docker socket and reads out Docker container automatically. It will a container’s name or tag or environment argument to a domain name.

This allows for DNS resolution of Docker containers and removes the need to bind ports. Which means that we can have as many parallel containers running as we want without adjusting the ports. Quite neat for multiple projects or micro services!

Don’t forget that they have to communicate with each other more often than not. It is important that a developer can just go into the project and run `docker-compose up`. The whole idea is that the operating system doesn’t matter and no completely new methods have to be developed for people using Windows.

Here is the nslookup output for reference:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> nslookup www.yahoo.com 172.17.0.1
Server:  UnKnown
Address:  172.17.0.1

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    new-fp-shed.wg1.b.yahoo.com
Addresses:  2a00:1288:110:c305::1:8000
          2a00:1288:110:c305::1:8001
          87.248.100.215
          87.248.100.216
Aliases:  www.yahoo.com

PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> nslookup www.yahoo.com
Server:  UnKnown
Address:  172.17.0.1

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    new-fp-shed.wg1.b.yahoo.com
Addresses:  2a00:1288:110:c305::1:8000
          2a00:1288:110:c305::1:8001
          87.248.100.216
          87.248.100.215
Aliases:  www.yahoo.com
```

And here is the docker-compose file that starts and controls the DNS server:

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  dnsdock:
    image: aacebedo/dnsdock:v1.16.4-amd64
    network_mode: bridge
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    container_name: dnsdock
    ports:
      - 172.17.0.1:53:53/udp
      #- 53:53/udp
    environment:
      - nameserver="8.8.8.8:53"
```

[image: docker network setup]

/etc/resolv.conf

```
 nameserver 172.17.0.1
```

ipconfig printout

```
PS C:\Users\<redacted>> ipconfig /all

Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : <redacted>
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . :
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No

Wireless LAN adapter LAN-Verbindung* 1:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : <redacted>
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Wireless LAN adapter WLAN:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Marvell AVASTAR Wireless-AC Network Controller
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : <redacted>
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.191(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : Thursday, January 14, 2021 7:07:52 AM
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : Thursday, January 14, 2021 8:07:50 AM
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.1
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.1
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 172.17.0.1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Ethernet adapter Bluetooth-Netzwerkverbindung:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Bluetooth Device (Personal Area Network)
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : <redacted>
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Ethernet adapter vEthernet (WSL):

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Hyper-V Virtual Ethernet Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : <redacted>
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 172.18.9.65(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.240
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Ethernet adapter vEthernet (Default Switch):

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Hyper-V Virtual Ethernet Adapter #2
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : <redacted>
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 172.18.63.65(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.240
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled
```

Comment: Something is wrong with the DNS records. You should perhaps include this info in your post. Do also [this troubleshooting](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/networking/dns/troubleshoot/troubleshoot-dns-server) and include the results.

Comment: I think I misunderstand your advise. The troubleshooting steps are all based upon nslookup not working. But nslookup does work. And what do you mean with the records are wrong? nslookup returns A records for internal as well as external entries. And those are all correct.

Comment: I'm asking if you are using nslookup as in the article, and for the inclusion of these records in your post.

Comment: I edited my question. I did it once exactly like it was described by the article and then again without naming the DNS server. Just to show that the DNS server is setup as my default DNS server.

Comment: I'm asking for the *zone records*. Perhaps [this link](https://www.virtualizationhowto.com/2019/07/export-and-import-dns-zone-with-powershell-from-one-server-to-another/) will clarify it.

Comment: Sorry for being daft, but I still don't get it. What I think I understand is this: A dns zone defines for which zones a dns server is authorative, right? The link and the command assumes that a dns server is installed in Windows. Zones are defined in the server, right? I use https://github.com/aacebedo/dnsdock in a docker container and I don't think any zones are configured or am I still not getting it?

Comment: The DNS configuration in the ubuntu server is key, how is it configured? what zones is it hosting (if any)? Maybe I need to see the configuration of the server fist, then any zone files.

Comment: @ram0nvaldez I added the docker-compose file that configures and starts the DNS server. No more configuration is done to the server. Everything else is on default. But I don't know how to find out the DNS zones. I also updated my question with the additional information that the ping from within WSL 2 Ubuntu works fine with lookup and everything, using the same DNS server. 

That's why I thought it must be a windows and not a DNS server problem. Sorry for omitting that.

Comment: (1) Your network architecture is somewhat unclear. Could you add a schema that shows hosts, docker containers, VMs and WSL? At least as regarding the DNS server, Windows, WSL and Ubuntu. (2) Did you check firewalls? (3) Does [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1571372/8672) pertain here?

Comment: I feel like I can help you get this running.  Need you to post the results of the following command from the ubuntu command line: cat /etc/resolv.conf

Comment: We haven't had any return from the poster for days. @TheCommoner282: If you have solved your problem, better post the solution as an answer (although you can't assign the bounty to yourself).

Comment: I apologise for not answering in days. I will come back to this in a few hours. The problem is not solved. I was just cut off the internet. In a few hours, I will be back with the computer with the issue and then I will post the additional requested information.

Comment: @harrymc I added a drawing of the setup

Comment: @apocalysque I added the resolv.conf to my post. It's just one line.

Comment: Can you disable IPv6 on the windows machine?  I think this will resolve your problems.

Comment: You need for it to work in windows, but do you need WSL2? I mean, Windows virtualizatin is pure sh*t. Use virtualbox or vmware and you'll have no problems. Thats how I have all my complex linux networks, with virtual routers and much more complex setups than that one, and works like a charm. I got no commercial or work relation with neither of those.

Comment: Have you tried the point (3) in my above comment?

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/compare-versions
Indeed WSL2 cannot reach IPv6 addresses as @apocalysque pointed out. I THINK you do that within Windows network adapter. That article has more info on the WSL2 networking issues/limitations.

Comment: @harrymc Sorry, forgot to mention, yes I tried that. It didn't change anything.

Comment: @apocalysque I forgot to mention that. But IPv6 was deactivated all along. I went through all adapter now and deactivated it in every single one, sadly to no avail.

Comment: I don't think you've completely disabled IPv6 because you're still getting IPv6 addresses on your NSLOOKUP.  Maybe try running the command: ping /4 yahoo.com.  This forces ping to use IPv4.  If it works then the problem is definitely IPv6.

Comment: Can you post the output from an "ipconfig" on the windows box?

Comment: @apocalysque ping /4 yahoo.com couldn't resolve the hostname either. I added the requested ipconfig /all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the DNS server to your other 2 "NICs".  The priority of your NICs might be causing one of those adapters to return a doesn't exist error on the DNS lookup because they don't have DNS servers set according to your ipconfig /all.  You could probably still fix it without doing this by adjusting your routing metrics or interface indexes in windows but that gets complicated.

Comment: Thank you. That did it. It works now.
Honestly, I poured so much time into this laptop and it works now! Thank you!