# Localhost not reachable on windows 10 wsl2

Tags: windows-10, networking, google-chrome, dns

Starting from monday, everytime i need to call my `localhost` Chrome say that is not available even if with `ping` i'm able to see it.
I already try to:

- delete Chrome dns cache
- delete firefix dns cache
- delete windows cache

After some research online and tests, i saw that with `ipconfig /flushdns` and a restart of the computer, start working again.

The problem is that everyday the problem persists and my routine now is:

- turn on the PC
- execute `ipconfig /flushdns` via windows terminal
- restart the PC
- run the application via WLS2

This is not sustainable, there is a way to make it working permanent?

Here is my hosts file:

```
# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
127.0.0.1       localhost
::1             localhost

# Added by Docker Desktop
192.168.X.X host.docker.internal 
192.168.X.X gateway.docker.internal
# To allow the same kube context to work on the host and the container:
127.0.0.1 kubernetes.docker.internal
# End of section
```

EDIT:
The application is running in ubuntu subsystem on wsl2, the browsers are running on windows.

EDIT:
Here is what the application prints (it's a django application):

```
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (5 silenced).
April 14, 2021 - 07:00:43
Django version 2.2.16, using settings 'geonode.local_settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
```

And this is the chrome screenshot:

[image]

Translated:

```
Unable to reach the website. 
Connection refused for localhost.
Try to:
- verify connection
- check proxy and firewall
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

Urls tested:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/
http://localhost:8000/
```

Comment: I see that you are using docker?  Can you paste the ipconfig /all in the question? I don't think flushdns needs to be done on 127.0.0.1 .

Comment: i have updated the question, since the application is running on ubuntu in the wsl2

Comment: 127.0.0.1 on the host I believe is different than the Ubuntu guest 127.0.0.1, though I'm not how sure how wsl actually virtualizes it.

Comment: What has changed on Monday? If System Restore is enabled, you could rollback to before it happened.

Comment: Just normal windows update, nothing special

Comment: Try System Restore to see if that windows update caused the problem.

Comment: already tried, the error still in place

Comment: What is the exact error code returned by Chrome, and what is the URL that is used?

Comment: Information added :)

Comment: (1) Does this error happen with other browsers than Chrome (and if yes which error messages)? (2) Add to the `hosts` file the line `127.0.0.1 localhost.` (with ending dot), clear Chrome DNS cache at `chrome://net-internals/#dns`, restart Chrome and try `http://localhost.:8000/`.

Comment: Firefox return the same error (Firefox is returning the same error as chrome (firefox canot make a connection with the server localhost:8000) By adding the localhost with the dot. Nothing change, the server is till not reachable

Comment: Strange that it works after restart, and in addition `localhost` is built-in and should not have anything to do with DNS. I wonder if this is a problem with your security software, so it might be worthwhile to disable it as test. See also if [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/1570310/network-problems-using-wsl2) is useful.

Comment: Network reset did not do the trick. I just tried to update WSL ubuntu distribution and now looks like that works. Gonna turn off the pc soon and see if now the issue is permanenlty solved

Comment: Run `ipconfig /displaydns` when you have issue & when it is working correctly

Comment: 1)What happens when you browser to `http://kubernetes.docker.internal:8000` ? 2)hosts shows two hostnames for same IP, what if comment out the first 127.0.0.1 so it'd be `#127.0.0.1       localhost`?

Comment: What is your Docker `run` command? Are you using `docker run -p 8000:8000`?

Comment: I'm not using  docker to run the application. It's running under the windows subsystem with the standard Django command: python manager.py runserver

Comment: Have you looked into [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/1570310/network-problems-using-wsl2)?

Comment: yes, not helpful

Comment: see https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4769 bug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of tentatives and patches, the only thing that worked was to disable the `fast startup` in windows settings

Answer (score 1):

My guess is what you are running into, based on how you've described it, is something (possibly kubernetes) is overwriting the 127.0.0.1 entry in your windows hostfile [consider this foundationally different from the ubuntu hosts file in the windows linux subsystem] and then when the ubuntu server is launched, by the windows linux subsystem, it creates its own hosts entry from that file, and creates its own loopback hostname that is incorrect.

Some point later, the windows hostsfile localhost entry is overwritten as myth2.localdomain, and when you attempt to access localhost in your browser it performs a lookup for myth2.localdomain and the request is sent to the ubuntu host, listening only on localhost for myth.localdomain  and the request fails.

you flush dns and restart, both systems have the same hosts file, the request work for a time.

you can avoid this in 2 ways.

first have your ubuntu app listen on 0.0.0.0:8000 (bind to all addresses, not just localhost)

second get the ubuntu system ip address or hostname, and make a host file entry on the windows machine with that address and ubuntuapp.whatever.com and use that URL in your browser

But you're right it's unsustainable, and not becuase of the windows linux subsystem, it's because your app is listening on a specific address, that is abstracted one layer from your windows machine, and that address pair is being overwritten by something else.

Comment: Unluckly i'm not using kubernetes. I'm just using the standard installation provided by microsoft. But as i wrote before, looks like that after upgrade the Ubuntu instance, the hosts is back to work. Btw, your ipotesis  is probably the reason of my issue

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled onto a similar problem this morning, as I was trying to access from my Windows 10 browsers a Jupyter instance running in a WSL2 process. While `curl` from the WSL2 console was finding the instance, the browsers were reporting connection errors.

After several unsuccessful tries, I finally found something that worked for my case. As I suspected my installation was outdated, I tried updating manually via CLI:

```
C:\Windows>wsl --update
Checking for updates...
The Windows Subsystem for Linux kernel can be manually updated with 'wsl --update', but automatic updates cannot occur due to your system settings.
To receive automatic kernel updates, please enable the Windows Update setting: 'Receive updates for other Microsoft products when you update Windows'.
For more information please visit https://aka.ms/wsl2kernel.
```

Apparently, WSL2 is not part of the normal Windows10 distribution but belongs to "other Microsoft products", and for reasons unknown I disabled the related update option. It's quite likely I disabled it some time ago, so I was running with an obsolete version - which, beside the localhost problem, was working perfectly.

Just like stated from the WSL2 cli, this must be enabled on `Windows Update > Advanced options > Receive Updates for other Microsoft products when you update Windows`. After enabling it, I finally received the WSL2 update and the localhost problem was fixed. I'm currently running `5.10.60.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2` on windows 10 version 19042.

Answer (score 0):

## [Accessing network applications](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/compare-versions)

*Legit copy/paste from Microsoft*

### Accessing Linux networking apps from Windows (localhost)

If you are building a networking app (for example an app running on a NodeJS or SQL server) in your Linux distribution, you can access it from a Windows app (like your Edge or Chrome internet browser) using localhost (just like you normally would).

However, if you are running an older version of Windows (Build 18945 or less), you will need to get the IP address of the Linux host VM (or update to the latest Windows version).

To find the IP address of the virtual machine powering your Linux distribution:

```
From your WSL distribution (ie Ubuntu), run the command: ip addr
Find and copy the address under the inet value of the eth0 interface.
If you have the grep tool installed, find this more easily by filtering the output with the command: ip addr | grep eth0
Connect to your Linux server using this IP address.
```

The picture below shows an example of this by connecting to a Node.js server using the Edge browser.
[image: Connect to NodeJS server with Edge]

### Additional networking considerations

**Connecting via remote IP addresses**

When using remote IP addresses to connect to your applications, they will be treated as connections from the Local Area Network (LAN). This means that you will need to make sure your application can accept LAN connections.

For example, you may need to bind your application to 0.0.0.0 instead of 127.0.0.1. In the example of a Python app using Flask, this can be done with the command: app.run(host='0.0.0.0'). Please keep security in mind when making these changes as this will allow connections from your LAN.

**Accessing a WSL 2 distribution from your local area network (LAN)**

When using a WSL 1 distribution, if your computer was set up to be accessed by your LAN, then applications run in WSL could be accessed on your LAN as well.

This isn't the default case in WSL 2. WSL 2 has a virtualized ethernet adapter with its own unique IP address. Currently, to enable this workflow you will need to go through the same steps as you would for a regular virtual machine. (We are looking into ways to improve this experience.)

Here's an example PowerShell command to add a port proxy that listens on port 4000 on the host and connects it to port 4000 to the WSL 2 VM with IP address 192.168.101.100.

Comment: I had already read this, bit was non useful.

Comment: What version of Windows do you have (Settings, System, About)? Build 18945 ([v1909 or lower](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/release-health/release-information)) using `localhost` doesn't work.

Comment: version windows 19042